# Reloading Rmd Html Document with Shiny Widets

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am looking at using Shiny widgets in an R-markdown file. I find this example, ran it in markdown, and then saved it as Html. However when I load it, it renders the widgets twice, and then hangs.

Is there a way I can avoid this, or is it a bug/known limitation in the system?

Here is the code:

````
---
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

### Here are two Shiny widgets

```{r echo = FALSE}
selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",
              choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20)

sliderInput("bw_adjust", label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
              min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)
```

### ...that build a histogram.

```{r echo = FALSE}
renderPlot({
  hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
       xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser eruption duration")

  dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input$bw_adjust)
  lines(dens, col = "blue")
})
```
````

It works fine when I compile it, but when I save it and then reload it into Chrome, IE, Edge, etc... I get this:

[image]

Comment: You are trying to save the interactive document as a web page, and then open it later?  It has to have the shiny server in the background running R to work.

Comment: Maybe. `rgl` seems to be able to take interactive input and render 3d graphics while changing the viewpoint without anything particular running in the background. I just want a simple dropdown...